# Infinite automatic repairinh

Tags: windows, windows-8

when I start up my computer, it takes me to the Automatic Repair page, giving me the options to 'continue', 'troubleshoot' or 'turn off pc'

Selecting the 'continue' option results in my computer restarting and coming back to the same page

Selecting Troubleshoot gives me various options to try and recover files, etc but I cannot do anything as it says I am not signed in as an administrator and that there aren't any administrator accounts on this pc. Choosing 'Forgotten your password or can't see your account' option results in the computer restarting!

Help!

Comment: If there are no admin accounts how do you ever install software?

Comment: It sounds like your system installation is corrupted beyond the ability for Windows to repair the damage time to reinstall Windows